# Change linked server login per-query

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, authentication

Given the situation below, can I specify that the pre-configured linked server login should *not* be used for a particular remote stored procedure call?

I have two SQL Server instances:

1. `[LOCAL]` running SQL Server 2012 with database `[A]` and
2. `[REMOTE]` running SQL Server 2008R2 with database `[B]`.

`[REMOTE]` is already set up as a linked server on `[LOCAL]`.  All users who can access `[LOCAL].[A]` can access `[REMOTE].[B]` (though not all its objects) through the SQL Server login `GenericUser`, which is already set up through a command on `[LOCAL]` such as:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname  = N'REMOTE',
                          @useself     = 'FALSE',
                          @rmtuser     = N'GenericUser',
                          @rmtpassword = N'TheGenericUserPassword'
```

This login works fine.  For authorization reasons, however, I would like to restrict access to a stored procedure `[dbo].[RemoteSP]` on `[REMOTE].[B]` to one particular Windows Authentication user, `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]`.  `[REMOTE].[B].[dbo].[RemoteSP]` will be called from within a stored procedure `[dbo].[LocalSP]` on `[LOCAL].[A]`, which `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]` may execute (as can other users, who will not call `[RemoteSP]`, as shown below).

The local stored procedure looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LocalSP]
    @Id INT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Do some stuff, then:
IF SUSER_NAME() = N'MYDOMAIN\OneUser'
BEGIN
    -- This syntax is invalid:
    EXEC [REMOTE].[B].[dbo].[RemoteSP] @MyVar = @Id AS SELF
END
```

Access is granted (e.g., by `GRANT EXEC ON [dbo].[RemoteSP] TO [MYDOMAIN\OneUser]`) on `[REMOTE]`, and the user `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]` exists on `[REMOTE]` and in `[REMOTE].[B]`.

Adding `WITH EXECUTE AS 'MYDOMAIN\OneUser'` to the `[RemoteSP]` definition, as [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53868) suggests, is unsatisfactory because I still need only `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]` to have access to the stored procedure.  Although [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/40331/4030) may be somewhat related, it is unanswered, and the linked chat room has been deleted.

I do not want to change the linked server login that `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]` would use for all queries, just this one.  I also would prefer to avoid a syntax like:

```
EXEC (N'EXEC [B].[dbo].[RemoteSP] @MyVar = ?', @Id) AS LOGIN = N'MYDOMAIN\OneUser' AT [REMOTE]
```

if for no other reason than there is little reason to use a dynamic string -- I have the stored procedure name, etc.

Comment: When `MYDOMAIN\OneUser` executes `LocalSP` and it calls `RemoteSP`, are you wanting `RemoteSP` to merely be restricted in its ability to be called by anyone else, or in addition to the restriction, for it to also execute within the security context of `MYDOMAIN\OneUser` instead of `GenericUser`?

Comment: @srutzky The former.  The security context within `RemoteSP` is not really a problem as long as only `MYDOMAIN\OneUser` can call `RemoteSP`.  Note that neither `GenericUser` nor `MYDOMAIN\OneUser` has direct access to the tables, views, etc. on `[REMOTE]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments on the question: The desire is to have `RemoteSP` on `[REMOTE]` execute within the security context of `GenericUser`, but *only* executable by `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]` even though *everyone* accesses `[REMOTE]` as `GenericUser` via the same Linked Server with a static security setup.

That seems like an inconsistent security setup. You have a single login on `[REMOTE]` that you want to have two different sets of permissions for. At the very least you will have to `DENY EXECUTE ON [RemoteSP] TO [GenericUser];` in order to prevent everyone outside of `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]` from executing the proc over the Linked Server. But you want it to execute in the context of `GenericUser` so you need to add `WITH EXECUTE AS 'GenericUser'` to that proc. Both of these steps get you the security context with the restriction on who can run it, but so far there is no way for `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]` to execute it either. And yes, it seems counter-intuitive to DENY execute to the User that is then used as the security context, but a) that be the requirements, and b) it does work as I tested it since it seemed like there was a possibility that SQL Server might give the "Did you even look at what you were trying to execute" error ;-).

Allowing only `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]` to execute means creating another Login on `[REMOTE]` for this purpose, call it `UserForRemoteSP`. Be sure to `GRANT EXECUTE ON [RemoteSP] TO [UserForRemoteSP];`.

Another desire is that `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]` still access `[REMOTE]` via the current Linked Server (and hence as `GenericUser`) for everything else besides `[RemoteSP]`. That can be accomplished by creating another Linked Server, call it `[REMOTE_SPECIAL]`, that has a mapped "local login to remote login" list with only `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]` defined in it, mapping to `UserForRemoteSP`. For the "For a login not defined in the list above, connections will:" option, select "Not be made".

Last step: in `[LocalSP]`, in the `IF SUSER_NAME` block, just do:

```sql
EXEC [REMOTE_SPECIAL].[B].[dbo].[RemoteSP] @MyVar = @Id;
```

Nobody else will be able to use the `[REMOTE_SPECIAL]` Linked Server, and the only thing that `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]` can use that Linked Server for is to execute `RemoteSP`, which will run as `GenericUser` due to the `EXECUTE AS` clause.

Comment: Excellent workaround.  This actually, in a roundabout way, removes my reason for not wanting to create a separate linked login for `[MYDOMAIN\OneUser]`.  I should be able just to make this login part of two different roles on `[REMOTE]`, which will actually accomplish what I want.  I'm not sure why I didn't think of that before.

Comment: Sounds good :). I added a small bit stating an acceptance of the odd nature of the setup on `[REMOTE]` but that it does work ;-). And yes, if you are using Role-based security then it makes the whole task even easier / cleaner.